# Spring integration : Failed to send message to channel 'executionFilterChannel' within timeout: -1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

Getting below error when i tried to use channel message store :- 
        org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to channel 'executionFilterChannel' within timeout: -1

```
        <int:channel id="executionFilterOutputChannel" />   
        <int:channel id="testChannel" /> 
        <int:channel id="executionFilterChannel">
           <int:queue message-store="channelMessageStore" />
                <int:interceptors>
                    <int:ref bean="kafkaIngestionInterceptor" />
                </int:interceptors>
        </int:channel>
        <bean id="kafkaIngestionInterceptor" class="com.xyz.report.interceptor.KafkaIngestionInterceptor" />

    <bean id="channelMessageStore"
class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="queryProvider" />
<property name="tablePrefix" value="QUEUE_" />
```

```
        <int:filter id="executionFilters"
                input-channel="testChannel" ref="executionFilter"
                method="productFilter" output-channel="executionFilterOutputChannel"
                discard-channel="exceptionFilterChannel" />

        <int:bridge id="bridgeChannel" input-channel="executionFilterChannel"
                output-channel="testChannel">
                <int:poller fixed-delay="10" max-messages-per-poll="1" >
                    <int:transactional transaction-manager="txManager" />
                </int:poller>
            </int:bridge>
            <bean id="txManager"
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            </bean>

    <int:service-activator id="outputKafkaActivator"
            input-channel="outputFromKafkaIngestion"
            output-channel="executionFilterChannel" method="getKafkaMessage">
            <bean class="com.xyz.report.service.KafkaListener" />
        </int:service-activator>
```

KafkaChannelInterceptor is a channel interceptor for channel "executionFilterChannel". It has below method :-

```
@Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        System.out.println("Before Sending =======================> " + channel  + "message : "+ message);
        return null;
    }
```

Full log :-

```
Message received from Kafka  ================================> GenericMessage [payload=EquityExecutionDetail [id=11, product=Equity, quantity=1000, isin=US2547895122, executedPrice=100.5, acctNo=5478962478, orderType=Market, expiryType=Day, buyOrSell=Buy, tradeDt=, execStatus=Fully Executed], headers={kafka_offset=73, PRODUCT=Equity, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=datapipeline.kafka.ingestion.test.1, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1587920627054, EVENT=CREATE, REGION=APAC}]
Before Sending =======================> executionFilterChannelmessage : GenericMessage [payload=EquityExecutionDetail [id=11, product=Equity, quantity=1000, isin=US2547895122, executedPrice=100.5, acctNo=5478962478, orderType=Market, expiryType=Day, buyOrSell=Buy, tradeDt=, execStatus=Fully Executed], headers={kafka_offset=73, PRODUCT=Equity, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, id=dad27393-5ef6-9280-8d3e-60c458312d65, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=datapipeline.kafka.ingestion.test.1, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1587920627054, EVENT=CREATE, REGION=APAC, timestamp=1587920627094}]
2020-04-26 22:33:47.096 ERROR 22640 --- [aContainer1-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = datapipeline.kafka.ingestion.test.1, partition = 0, offset = 73, CreateTime = 1587920627054, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 335, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = PRODUCT, value = [34, 69, 113, 117, 105, 116, 121, 34]), RecordHeader(key = EVENT, value = [34, 67, 82, 69, 65, 84, 69, 34]), RecordHeader(key = REGION, value = [34, 65, 80, 65, 67, 34]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 80, 82, 79, 68, 85, 67, 84, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 69, 86, 69, 78, 84, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 82, 69, 71, 73, 79, 78, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = EquityExecutionDetail [id=11, product=Equity, quantity=1000, isin=US2547895122, executedPrice=100.5, acctNo=5478962478, orderType=Market, expiryType=Day, buyOrSell=Buy, tradeDt=, execStatus=Fully Executed])

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to channel 'executionFilterChannel' within timeout: -1
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:118) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$200(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:63) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:372) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:352) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:925) [spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:909) [spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:860) [spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:738) [spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:622) [spring-kafka-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

Please help me as i am stuck for 3 days now.

Comment: What is your `channelMessageStore`? What is your `kafkaIngestionInterceptor`? Typically I see such an issue when the thread sending to a `QueueChannel` is interrupted. Any chances that yo can share with us a minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: Hello Artem, I have edited the code above, basically my application flow is like :- Listening message from kafka topic and sending to execution filter channel which has message store. So polling the message using bridge and sending to test channel(this test channel is actual input for execution filter). My application is working fine when i remove the bridge and message store. Please help me to understand what i am doing wrong here with messagestore/bridge implementation.

Comment: Hi Artem, It seems that kafkaIngestionInterceptor is causing the issue, i have removed it and the message store is working fine now. But not sure how to use interceptor in this case to check the pre/post send details

Comment: You need to show the `KafkaIngestionInterceptor` code.

Comment: See, my answer: the `return null;` is a cause of an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the interceptor is like this:

```
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    System.out.println("Before Sending =======================> " + channel  + "message : "+ message);
    return null;
}
```

You return `null`. Therefore nothing actually send to the channel. That's why you get that exception.

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Invoked before the Message is actually sent to the channel.
 * This allows for modification of the Message if necessary.
 * If this method returns {@code null} then the actual
 * send invocation will not occur.
 */
@Nullable
default Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
```

There is a debug message on the matter for your convenience:

```
message = interceptor.preSend(message, channel);
if (message == null) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug(interceptor.getClass().getSimpleName()
                                + " returned null from preSend, i.e. precluding the send.");
        }
        afterSendCompletion(previous, channel, false, null, interceptorStack);
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the debug message, it will help